# how to speed up the following excel vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have not been doing a lot of VBA and am relatively new to it all. 
The following VBA takes too long to run currently, it takes 5 min!

Can anybody offer advice to speed it up? I have already added a few things. I think it is mostly due to amount of data in my document. I have about 20 tabs with data, and the macro has to run through all VISIBLE tabs, but I didn't know how to write a code to limit this.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    Application.StatusBar = False

On Error Resume Next

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
    With ws
    ws.Activate 'this part ensures each seperate tab is activated and the below code is run through
    Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94 'this line determines the column width
    Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 6.56 'this line determines the column width
    Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("F").ColxumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
    Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 6.56
    Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 6.56
    Wsh.Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'Set Activesheet to Page Break Preview Mode
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    End With

Next ws
Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file
'Worksheets(1).Activate 'this line make sure view is at first tab

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

Comment: The blocks starting with `Application.Screenupdating` etc. you have at the start and end of your macro should be switched around entirely. You want screenupdating, events, and alerts OFF during your macro. But now you switch all that ON specifically, and OFF at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, I've simply amended the ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents & DisplayAlerts to False before running the Loop and then reset them to True once finished:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
        ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94 'this line determines the column width
        ws.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 6.56 'this line determines the column width
        ws.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        ws.Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        ws.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        ws.Columns("F").ColxumnWidth = 10.11
        ws.Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
        ws.Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10.11
        ws.Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
        ws.Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        ws.Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 6.56
        ws.Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 6.56
        ws.Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Next ws


Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

Comment: this helped a lot. code now takes 1:23 min, but this is still too long. I am seeing how to possibly make my loop more efficient, but not sure how to tackle this. for example, run code only on visible sheets?

Comment: @Xabier Let OP accept the answer he/she prefers without persuasion.

Answer (score 0):

The macro speed can be increased by setting the column widths for multiple columns in one step.

e.g. `Columns("A:J").ColumnWidth = 13.56`

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
  If ws.Visible <> False Then        
     With ws
        .Columns("A:J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 6.56
        .Columns("F:I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
        .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
        .Columns("K:L").ColumnWidth = 6.56

        Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    End with
 End if
Next ws


Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

Comment: your with ws should not include the range activewindow parts. And range is missing a `.` before it.

Answer (score 0):

To further speed up the process from what Xabier already done you can do more than one column width at the time.
There are a few that are the same so grouping them is a good idea.

Also, do you really need to do this every time you open the workbook? I mean if you set the width once, why would it need to be changed again next time you open the workbook?

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
    If ws.Visible = True Then ' is worksheet visible?
        ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94 'this line determines the column width
        ws.Range("B:B,K:L").ColumnWidth = 6.56 'this line determines the column width
        ws.Range("C:E,J:J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
        ws.Range("F:F,H:I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
        ws.Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
        ws.Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
   end if
Next ws


Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

This means it will change all column widths with five lines of code instead of 12

You could also first check if the columns widths need to be changed before doing it.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
    If ws.Visible = True Then' is worksheet visible?
        if ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth <> 0.94 and ws.Range("B:B,K:L").ColumnWidth <> 6.56 and ws.Range("F:F,H:I").ColumnWidth <> 10.11 and ws.Columns("G").ColumnWidth <> 6.11 then
            ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94 'this line determines the column width
            ws.Range("B:B,K:L").ColumnWidth = 6.56 'this line determines the column width
            ws.Range("C:E,J:J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
            ws.Range("F:F,H:I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
            ws.Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
        end if

        ws.Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
   end if
Next ws


Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot those two. I had the same problem in the other code but forgot the if statement.

Comment: well, there are multiple users of the document and people will start to adjust the width. and higher management does not want to open a document and that they themselves have to adjust the widths again